# How to move an image to a folder GitHub

Tags: github

I want to move an image in my GitHub repository to a new folder. I know to move a text file you can click the edit icon in the top right but there is no edit icon for pictures. How can I move the picture on GitHub in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Update: The OP changed the title **after** my answer. The original question said **GitHub Desktop** not **GitHub Browser** - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52977306/revisions

[image]

---

GitHub Desktop tracks all changes to all files as you edit them directly in the file system.

Just move the files directly using Windows Explorer and commit your changes to the repository using GitHub Desktop after moving the file.

Step-by-step instructions here:

> **[Committing and reviewing changes to your project](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing-to-projects/committing-and-reviewing-changes-to-your-project/)**

---

You might also be interested in reading the other topics in the documentation, to get up to speed:

https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing-to-projects/

[image: Contributing to projects with GitHub Desktop]

Comment: @Chris Unfortunately the OP changed the title **after** my answer. The original question said **GitHub Desktop** - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52977306/revisions

Answer (score 0):

Images are binary data. Adding, removing, and even updating those images can cause unnecessary usage of your repository's space. This is because images, videos, and other binary data are larger than the text files where our code is written. For personal projects, one could use this site (or another) to upload all of your images: https://imgbb.com/. Then URLs of each image will be provided for use anywhere in an app without the need to store those images in an actual repo.